# Using recursive functions and Heredoc together

Tags: php, function, recursion, heredoc

I would like to echo a large bunch of text without having to painfully escape all the characters, will be a nightmare for debugging, and would like to use heredoc.

I have read the documents and am unable to fix this.

```
function MySwal($items, $k){
    if ($k!=0) $k = $k+1; 

    if ($items[$k] != "end") {
    //if ($items != "end") {
        echo <<<MySWALSTUFF_A
          <p> at {$k} : processing {$items[$k]} . next item is {$items[$k+1]}
        MySWALSTUFF_A;
        //include this later
        echo MySwal($items, ($k+1)); //recursive function
    } else { //else  for if item is !=end 
        echo "<HR><h3>This is the end, beautiful friend... </h3>";
    }//if for item != end ends here :-)     
}
```

and  call this with `MySwal ($myarray, 0)` where the last item in the array is "end"

Now, the recursion doesn't show the output of the function after the 1st time. if `$myarray` has `array("one", "two", "end")`, the heredoc above is executed only for "one".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$k` jumps directly from `0` to `2`, because you're incrementing it twice…

Answer (score 1):

It's because you increment `k` in the function:

```
if ($k!=0) $k = $k+1;
```

and also in the call to the function:

```
echo MySwal($items, ($k+1));
```

This causes it to skip the value at index 1 in the array. Remove the increment inside the function and it works fine: https://3v4l.org/SuXLR